# react material-ui popover while fullscreen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way I can adjust a `<Popover>` element when fullscreen (`Element.requestFullscreen()`)?

By default its DOM is placed on the body root, and for so, it doesn't show when the element that triggered it to appear is fullscreen.

Because of this, all menus I have on my fullscreen element are never shown until it leaves fullscreen.

Comment: Yeah I just ran into this. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @FrankHale I gave up and made my own implementation with the popover element mounted inside the element which would go fullscreen.

Answer (score 3):

You have to customize  **container** prop of the  `Popover`

component. `container` is the node of DOM which is Popover mounted to. By default it is  `document.body`. That is why `Popover` is mounted behind the element that is in full-screen mode.
You have to set container node to the element which is going to be in full-screen mode.

Answer (score 2):

props container of the Popover component:

```
const containerRef = useRef(null);

<div ref={containerRef}>
   <button onClick={handleOpen}>open</button>
   <Popover container={containerRef.current}>
      ...
   </Popover>
</div>
```

Comment: It might be helpful for other readers if you would add some informations about what the code does in detail.